# Why can't i place a button to a frame tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

class page:
    def pageNext(self, pageNext):
        self.pageNext = pageNext
        pageNext.tkraise()
    def button(self, window, text, x, y, command = None):
        self.window = window
        self.text = text
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.command = command
        button = Button(window, text = text, command = lambda:command)
        button.place(x = x, y = y)
    def label(self, window, text, x, y, header = False):
        self.window = window
        self.text = text
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.header = header
        if header == True:
            label = Label(window, font = "Helvetica 16 bold italic", text = text)
        else:
            label = Label(window, text = text)
        label.place(x = x, y = y)
    def newPage(self, window):
        self.window = window
        pageNew = Frame(window)
        pageNew.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "News")
        return pageNew
root = Tk()
page = page()
```

Guys when I try to create a frame using `pageWelcome = page.newPage(root)` and place a button using `page.button(pageWelcome)` and say `page.pageNext(pageWelcome)` it doesn't place the button but when I place a button like `page.button(root)` it places the button to the screen. I can't see which part of my code is broken. Can someone help?

P.S: I made this class basing to my first GUI. In that times i couldn't use classes but my code was working fine.

[My code](https://paste.ee/p/BIkxY)

Comment: Are labels being displayed properly?

Comment: When i use it like `page.label(root, "start", 150, 300, True)` it does but when i use it like `page.label(pageWelcome, "start", 150, 300, True)` it doesn't works.

Comment: Please post your code that isn't working. Ideally something runnable or as close to that as you can get.

Comment: Read [Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/7414759) and use that pattern.

Comment: "but when I place a button like page.button(root) it places the button to the screen" Really? You want tell us that you are able create the button like so <page.button(root)> without getting TypeError because of missing positional arguments???

Comment: @Turjak_art no, ofcourse i will get an error for that. I meant that when i fill the rest of the parts like `text`, `x` and `y` (`command` is optinal) it works normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i couldn't find what was wrong with my code so i started for "how to change page tkinter". One of the results was very simple -easy to understand- and i changed all of my code according to that code. I am putting here [the tutorial link](https://pythonprogramming.net/change-show-new-frame-tkinter/) and [the credit link](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfzlCWGWYyIQ0aLC5w48gBQ) if there is anyone interested.